# Nginx user for cron.sh in Mavericks

Tags: cron, ce-1.9.0.1, nginx, user

I noticed that the `nginx` processes have two different users: `root` is the user which runs the master process, and `nobody` is the default one for workers.

To which user must I place the `cron` job ? I believe it's the one who runs the workers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather gnaw my hand off than run anything from cron with root privileges. Run Magento cron script as nobody. Besides, you're executing command line PHP, not nginx.

Comment: http://www.webguys.de/magento/tuerchen-08-magento-cron-demystified/ says cron must run as webserver user. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: The reason being that whoever has an access to cron.php / cron.sh file has automatically those privileges those scripts were ran as. Run them as a root and you have a security hole as big as Pacific ocean (minus water).

Comment: I understand. My comment was due to you pointed that I was not executing nginx, but php scripts. So I wanted to clarify the instructions at that link.

Comment: :) cron is a very important part of magento and at the same time too often overlooked / misunderstood. It's good that people write about it.